# JAVA: A Method show differents outputs for two differents objects

Tags: java, oop

I have a problem with my code. I have two classes: Alumno and Tutor. Alumno have two methods: guardarCalificacion() to set a grade for the student and the other is mostrarCalificacion to show the grade. In the main method when I call the mostrarCalificacion() method but with a Tutor object it shows a 0 like grade in console but it must show a 8 because I assigned a 8 like a grade for the Alumno object. Here is the code:

Alumno class:

```
public class Alumno { 

    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String correo;
    private double calificacion;
    
    //Constructor
    public Alumno(int id, String nombre, String apellido, String correo, double calificacion){
        this.id=id;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.correo=correo;
       
               
    }
    
    // Metodo setter para establecer calificacion
    public void guardarCalificacion(double nota){
        calificacion=nota;
    }
    
    //Metodo getter para obtener la calificacion
    public double mostrarCalificaciones(){
        return calificacion;
    }
}
```

Tutor class:

```
  public class Tutor extends Alumno{
    
    
  public Tutor(int id, String nombre, String apellido, String correo, double alumno){
      super(id, nombre, apellido, correo, alumno); 
      
  }
  
 
     //Metodo getter para obtener la calificacion
    @Override
    public double mostrarCalificaciones(){
        double alumno=super.mostrarCalificaciones();
        return alumno;
    }
  
}
```

Main Method:

```
public class Uso_Escuela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alumno alumno=new Alumno(1, "a", "b", "c", 10);
        Tutor tutor=new Tutor(2, "a", "b", "c",10);
        
       alumno.guardarCalificacion(8);
       System.out.println(alumno.mostrarCalificaciones());
       System.out.println(tutor.mostrarCalificaciones());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
8.0
0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the issue is: `calificacion` was not set on your Constructor for the Alumno class

```
//Constructor
public Alumno(int id, String nombre, String apellido, String correo, double calificacion){
    this.id=id;
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellido=apellido;
    this.correo=correo;
   
           
}
```

Add this line on your constructor to set `calificacion` and it should work:

```
this.calificacion = calificacion
```

With your example, once the issue is fixed, the resulting print for the second line `System.out.println(tutor.mostrarCalificaciones());`  will be `10.0` not `8.0` as you assumed, because during the initialization of your `Tutor` object, you have set `10.0` for the field `alumno` which will then be mapped to the `calificacion` field on your `Alumna` class.

Also, with this line:

```
   alumno.guardarCalificacion(8);
```

Not because you assigned a value to a field of a Parent class `Alumno`, it would be inherited by the child class `Tutor`. **That's not how inheritance works.** `alumno` and `tutor` are of different instance/object. `tutor` will only inherit the fields and methods of the **Alumno Class** but not the values you set for the `alumno` object.

Answer (score 0):

Every new object you create is completely unrelated to other objects and updating the value of one object won't affect the other object.

Here, you created two objects, `alumno` and `tutor`, they both have been assigned different memory and are independent of each other. So updating `alumno` won't update the `tutor` object. To update `tutor` you'll need to call

```
tutor.guardarCalificacion(8);
```

The `guardarCalificacion()` method will be inherited from the parent class i.e. `Alumno` to the child class i.e. `Tutor`.

Also you can remove the overriding method `mostrarCalificaciones()` from `Tutor` class as it will be inherited from the parent class. You override the method only when you want to change the method defination.